# File "server.py", line 1, in <module> import http.server ImportError: No module named http.server

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, module, importerror

```
import http.server
import socketserver
from google_search import chatbot_query

PORT = 8080
DIRECTORY = 'public'


class Handler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, directory=DIRECTORY, **kwargs)

    def do_POST(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        post_body = self.rfile.read(content_length)
        self.end_headers()
        print('user query', post_body)
        google_search_chatbot_reply = chatbot_query(post_body)
        self.wfile.write(str.encode(google_search_chatbot_reply))


with socketserver.TCPServer(('', PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    print('serving at port', PORT)
    try:
        httpd.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    httpd.server_close()
```

Comment: Check this out,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444343/no-module-named-http-server

Comment: You are running Python 3 code on Python 2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [no module named http.server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444343/no-module-named-http-server)